# Trying to get property of a non-object in

Tags: php, html

```html
-- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 4.0.4.2
-- http://www.phpmyadmin.net
--
-- Host: localhost
-- Generation Time: Sep 05, 2019 at 03:50 AM
-- Server version: 5.6.13
-- PHP Version: 5.4.17

SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET time_zone = "+00:00";


/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;

--
-- Database: `smc tuckshop`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `food`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `food` (
  `FoodID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `FoodName` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `FoodImage` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `FoodSize` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `Price` decimal(7,2) NOT NULL,
  `Day` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`FoodID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Dumping data for table `food`
--

INSERT INTO `food` (`FoodID`, `FoodName`, `FoodImage`, `FoodSize`, `Price`, `Day`) VALUES
(190201, 'Beef & Gravy Roll', 'beefgravyroll.jpg', '', '4.00', 'Monday'),
(190202, 'Meatball Sub', 'meatballsub.jpg', '', '4.50', 'Monday'),
(190203, 'Pork Tacos', 'porktacos1.jpg', '1x', '2.50', 'Monday'),
(190204, 'Pork Tacos', 'porktacos2.jpg', '2x ', '4.50', 'Monday'),
(190205, 'Chicken Nachos', 'chickennachos.jpg', '', '4.50', 'Tuesday'),
(190206, 'Curried Sausages', 'curriedsausagesL.jpg', 'Large', '4.00', 'Tuesday'),
(190207, 'Curried Sausages', 'curriedsausagesS.jpg', 'Small', '2.00', 'Tuesday'),
(190208, 'Steak Burger', 'steakburger.jpg', '', '4.50', 'Tuesday'),
(190209, 'Mexican Chicken Burger', 'mexicanchickenburger.jpg', '', '5.00', 'Wednesday'),
(190210, 'Chicken Drumstick and Wedges', 'chickendrumstick.jpg', '', '5.00', 'Wednesday'),
(190211, 'Honey Chicken Noodles', 'honeychickennoodles.jpg', '', '4.00', 'Wednesday'),
(190212, 'Curry Chicken Pie and Wedges', 'currychickenpie.jpg', '', '6.00', 'Thursday'),
(190213, 'Bacon and Egg Burger', 'bacon.jpg', '', '5.00', 'Thursday'),
(190214, 'Quesadillas', 'quesadillas.jpg', '', '4.00', 'Thursday'),
(190215, 'Beef & Gravy Roll', 'beefgravyroll.jpg', '', '4.00', 'Friday'),
(190216, 'Enchiladas', 'enchiladas.jpg', '', '4.50', 'Friday'),
(190217, 'Lasagne', 'lasagne.jpg', '', '4.00', 'Friday'),
(190218, 'Gourmet Burger', 'gourmetburger.jpg', '', '5.00', 'Friday'),
(190219, 'Sushi', 'sushi.jpg', '', '3.50', 'Friday'),
(190220, 'Beef Pies', 'beefpies.jpg', '', '4.00', 'Everyday'),
(190221, 'Pepper Pies', 'pepperpies.jpg', '', '4.00', 'Everyday'),
(190222, 'Sausage Roll', 'sausageroll.jpg', '', '3.00', 'Everyday'),
(190223, 'Sauce', 'sauce.jpg', '', '0.50', 'Everyday'),
(190224, 'Bacon Wraps', 'baconwraps.jpg', '', '2.00', 'Breakfast'),
(190225, 'Bacon Toasties', 'bacontoasties.jpg', '', '2.00', 'Breakfast'),
(190226, 'Bacon Muffin', 'baconmuffin.jpg', '', '2.50', 'Breakfast'),
(190227, 'Bacon & Egg Wraps', 'baconeggwraps.jpg', '', '3.00', 'Breakfast'),
(190228, 'Bacon & Egg Toasties', 'baconeggtoasties.jpg', '', '3.00', 'Breakfast'),
(190229, 'Bacon & Egg Muffin', 'baconeggmuffin.jpg', '', '3.50', 'Breakfast'),
(190230, 'Milk', 'milkmilk1.jpg', '1 litre', '3.00', 'Drink'),
(190231, 'Chocolate Milk', 'chocolatemilk500.jpg', '500ml', '3.50', 'Drink'),
(190232, 'Chocolate Milk', 'chocolatemilk300.jpg', '300ml', '3.00', 'Drink'),
(190233, 'Strawberry Milk', 'strawberrymilk500.jpg', '500ml', '3.50', 'Drink'),
(190234, 'Strawberry Milk', 'strawberrymilk300.jpg', '300ml', '3.00', 'Drink'),
(190235, 'Caramel Milk', 'caramelmilk500.jpg', '500ml', '3.50', 'Drink'),
(190236, 'Caramel Milk', 'caramelmilk300.jpg', '300ml', '3.00', 'Drink'),
(190237, 'Passionfruit Yoghurt', 'passionfruityoghurt.jpg', '', '2.50', 'Everyday'),
(190238, 'Mango Yoghurt', 'mangoyoghurt.jpg', '', '2.50', 'Everyday'),
(190239, 'Raspberry Yoghurt', 'raspberryyoghurt.jpg', '', '2.50', 'Everyday'),
(190240, 'Juice', 'juicejuice375.jpg', '375ml', '3.50', 'Drink'),
(190241, 'Juice', 'juicejuice250.jpg', '250ml', '1.80', 'Drink'),
(190242, 'Water', 'waterwater1.5.jpg', '1.5 litre', '2.50', 'Drink'),
(190243, 'Water', 'waterwater1.jpg', '1 litre', '2.00', 'Drink'),
(190244, 'Water', 'waterwater600.jpg', '600ml', '1.50', 'Drink'),
(190245, 'Museli', 'museli.jpg', '', '0.50', 'Everyday'),
(190246, 'Fresh fruit', 'freshfruitL.jpg', 'Large', '2.00', 'Everyday'),
(190247, 'Fresh fruit', 'freshfruitS.jpg', 'Small ', '1.00', 'Everyday'),
(190248, 'Meat & Salad Rolls', 'meatsaladrolls.jpg', '', '5.00', 'Everyday'),
(190249, 'Meat & Salad Wraps', 'meatsaladwraps.jpg', '', '3.00', 'Everyday'),
(190250, 'Egg & Lettuce Sandwhiches', 'egglettucesandwhiches.jpg', '', '4.00', 'Everyday'),
(190251, 'Ham, Cheese and Salad Sandwich', 'hamcheese.jpg', '', '4.00', 'Everyday'),
(190252, 'Meat & Salad Bowl', 'meatbowlL.jpg', 'Large', '6.00', 'Everyday'),
(190253, 'Meat & Salad Bowl', 'meatbowlS.jpg', 'Small', '3.00', 'Everyday');

/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
```

I need to input a database into my website for major assessment for school, however, when I attempt to display the tables, it instead states Notice: Trying to get property of non-object.

I've tried adding "[]" to replace the "->" as I read elsewhere it may work, evidently it did not.
I don't know what else to try as my knowledge base regarding PHP is minimal.

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT Monday, Everyday FROM food";

$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result-> num_rows > 0) {
// output data of each row
while($rows = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
#print_r ($row);
$FoodId = $rows["FoodID"];
$FoodImage = $rows["FoodImage"];
$FoodName = $rows["FoodName"];
$FoodSize = $rows["FoodSize"];
$Price = $rows["Price"];
?>
```

Expected results are that it will display a table with the food items to be purchased.

> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\Users\wightmana-19\Desktop\USB - PHP and MySQL\root\Tuckshop\Monday.php on line 124

Comment: <?php
                  $sql = "SELECT Monday, Everyday FROM food";
      
                  $result = $conn->

Comment: it left out the beginning of the code which is here in comments as well.

Comment: What does Monday & Everyday refers in select clause?

Comment: What does print_r($row) outputs. Include table structure, some data and expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should include all fields in `SELECT` clause which you want to access in PHP code i.e. include `FoodID, FoodImage, FoodName, FoodSize, Price`.

So your query should be:

```
SELECT
    FoodID, FoodImage, FoodName, FoodSize, Price, `Day`
FROM food
WHERE `Day` IN ('Monday', 'Everyday');
```

Note: Don't know what `Monday, Everyday` represent in select clause but if you want some filters than use `WHERE` clause.

Comment: Monday and Everyday are the categories I'm trying to use to sort and explicitly select only the data I wish to use within the columns

Comment: To sort and explicitly select you have to use where clause. If you can share you sample data, we can discuss.

Comment: Turns out I forgot to include $Day = $rows["Day"];

Comment: how do i share the data?

Comment: Take a screenshot or export data as SQL statement

Comment: how do I add a picture or file?

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/344851/how-do-you-add-a-screenshot-image-to-your-stack-overflow-post

Comment: @Mr.Student.exe, see my updated answer. Verify whether it solves your problem or not.

Comment: @Mr. Student.exe, if it solves your problem, accept the answer. :)